# C# Lambda won't finish executing

Tags: c#, ios, lambda, zxing

Below is a code snippet which I have written.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
  BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => scannerView.StartScanning(result =>
  {

      if (!ContinuousScanning)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Stopping scan...");
          scannerView.StopScanning();
      }

      var evt = this.OnScannedResult;
      if (evt != null)
          evt(result);


    try
    {
        this.NavigationController.PushViewController(product, true);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception("Unable to push to the product page", e);   
    }

  }, this.ScanningOptions));

});
```

But when I try to run the PushViewController, I get the following error message:

DECODE FAILED: System.Exception: An error occurred when trying to redirect to the product screen ---> System.Exception: Unable to push to the product page ---> UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException: UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread.

How would I go about running something like this from within the lambda?

Comment: Are you sure the final two outputs never execute? They're going to be appearing *before* the two you are seeing, so maybe you missed them? `lambda finished...` will be displayed before the task even starts, and `some output 2` will be output when the tasks starts, but before it finishes.

Comment: Hmmm, you are right actually!

How would I go about running some code AFTER the lambda finishes though?

Comment: I've left an answer as it's too much to put into one comment. However, `"Some output 1"` is likely what you're looking for - it will execute at the end of `BeginInvokeOnMainThread()` (which itself will likely be the last thing executed in the task). Note the liberal use of 'likely'. When dealing with `async` programming, it's very difficult (and also usually superfluous) to explicitly state 'what happens when' when code is distributed between threads

Comment: something related to iOS here? I am curious.

Comment: Thanks guys, I had initially thought it was not possible to run code within the lambda to exit the view, thanks for clearing that up Rob. I'm getting the following error though when I try to push to a new view. Just edited my original post now

Answer (score 1):

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => // <-- This starts a task which may or may not be on a 
                            // separate thread. It is non-blocking, and as such, code 
                            // after it is likely to execute before the task starts
{
  BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => scannerView.StartScanning(result =>
  // This invokes a method on the main thread, which may or may not be the current thread
  // Again, it's non-blocking, and it's very likely code after this will execute first

  {

      if (!ContinuousScanning)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Stopping scan...");
          scannerView.StopScanning();
      }

      var evt = this.OnScannedResult;
      if (evt != null)
          evt(result);

      Console.WriteLine("Some output 1"); // <-- This output is executed once the entire
                                          // task has been completed, which is I believe
                                          // what you're looking for
  }, this.ScanningOptions));

  Console.WriteLine("Some output 2");
});

Console.WriteLine("lambda finished...");
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, you are right. I've updated my original post to show you the issue I was experiencing originally with running code within the lambda. Could you advise?

Answer (score 0):

For those who are struggling with this, I managed to get it working by wrapping my code within InvokeOnMainThread()

```
                    InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                         this.NavigationController.PushViewController(product, true);
                    });
```